# Rails rsolr 1.0.12 Errno::ECONNREFUSED depreciated, but why not working in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails, rsolr

I'm working with Rails 4.0.4 en Sunspot as a search engine. Works just fine in production. Using rsolr 1.0.12

```
[DEPRECATION] `RSolr.escape` is deprecated (and incorrect).  Use `Rsolr.solr_escape` instead.
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - {:data=>"fq=type%3ACompany&q=design&fl=*+score&qf=name_text&defType=edismax&start=0&rows=30", :method=>:post, :params=>{:wt=>:ruby}, :query=>"wt=ruby", :headers=>{"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}, :path=>"select", :uri=>#<URI::HTTP:0x007ff3594ca8e8 URL:http://localhost:8983/solr/production/select?wt=ruby>, :open_timeout=>nil, :read_timeout=>nil, :retry_503=>nil, :retry_after_limit=>nil}):
```

is this because of the URL:http://localhost:8983 and so on? and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `Errno::ECONNREFUSED` error comes when you didn't start your solr. To start use:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
```

And I'm too is searchin about the deprecation warning and I Found this [LINK](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/661)